guardar una fila de fechas a datagridview y se guarde en campo fecha de sql desde c#
Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual tiene como objetivo realizar una programación de lo que se debe de producir por día en un taller de costura, para eso realice un apartado donde el encargado de realizar esas programaciones "importe el excel al datagridview y despues se registra al sql" esta es la forma de como lo estoy haciendo ahorita pero el archivo va con fechas por cada trabajo que se debe hacer por día como lo muestra en la siguiente imagen.

Pero quisiera que se pudiera hacer así poner las fechas en horizontal y poder guardarlas en campo fecha de sql server. Les agradecería mucho si me dan alguna idea de como poder lograrlo.


Estas pidiendo dos cosas distintas... eso que mostras abajo, es una tabla pivotante, pero no se guarda asi, se guarda como lo tenes arriba... y se muestra como lo tenes abajo...

Buenas tardes @gbianchi.  Entonces lo correcto es guardarlo como lo tengo arriba y después se pivotea desde SQL. Lo que quisiera saber es como puedo hacer un formato para el ingeniero que carga su programación de sus objetivos por día y registrarlo en sql server, porque si es asi como lo tengo en la primera imagen seria poner varias fechas y si lo hago como la parte de abajo seria mucho mejor, o que idea me puedes proponer

ah no se.. para ideas visuales, mejor un diseñador grafico... mostrar, se puede mostrar como quieras.. guardar, se guarda como se ve alla arriba...

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
